(vnv) next to pronunciation of French words on Wiktionary
On Wiktionary, next to the IPA pronunciation of some French words, such as crevé, vit, envoûtant, there is a mysterious abbreviation(?) (vnv). What does it mean? It's never annotated or linked to any explanation.

These pages were modified by a bot on the English wiktionary. I reported the issue to the page maintainers.
It is a tag that was possibly related to verbs, maybe verb-noun-verb but it doesn't look to be documented.
All these entries should be corrected now.

Thanks. I was really confused about this.

So we will probably never know what it was supposed to mean.

@PeterShor Maybe nobody ever knew what it was supposed to mean. As far as I understand, the idea is for IPA to be automatically generated from the spelling. 'pos=vlv' might have been a typo that survived and reproduced itself :-) After disabling the effect of this tag, they now plan to remove it from the wiktionary source pages where it appears. Let's see how it goes.

It's clearer if you turn your monitor upside down to read it in IPA.  At least that's sort of what I thought trying to parse it.
